# Hadoop tasktracker node fails to reconnect due to slow startup of jobtracker

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration

I'm running a hadoop cluster (version 0.20.205), and I have to periodically deploy new code to the cluster, which involves taking the cluster down and bringing it back up again with the new code. My problem is that, for reasons that are too complicated to go into here, I can't ensure that the jobtracker comes up before the tasktracker nodes. I see tasktracker nodes try to connect to the jobtracker that hasn't come up yet, and shut down after printing this to the logs:

```
- Can not start task tracker because java.io.IOException: Call to <jobtracker node> failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1103)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1071)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:429)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$3.run(TaskTracker.java:794)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:790)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1428)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3674)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:55)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:128)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:342)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:800)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:745)

- SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at <tasktracker node>
************************************************************/
```

My question is this: is there some way I can configure the tasktracker nodes to try to reconnect in a loop until they've successfully connected to the jobtracker?

Thanks for the help!